# Warning with create-react-native-app

Tags: react-native

I try to create a react native application using "create-react-native-app" but i have few warnings.

Despiste of those warnings, the process seems ok, I get "Happy hacking!" message and list of "yarn" commands I can use to test my application, but the simulator failed to launch my application. i guess I have to fix the dependencies issues first, but do know how to make it properly coz I only the "create-react-native-app" command?

```
warning react-native-scripts > xdl > auth0-js > xtend > object-keys@0.4.0: 
warning "react-redux@5.0.5" has unmet peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0".
warning "react-native-maps@0.15.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@>=15.4.0".
warning "react-native-branch@2.0.0-beta.3" has incorrect peer dependency "react@>=15.4.0".
warning "lottie-react-native@1.1.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@>=15.3.1".
```

Thanks,
Orb

Comment: I have updated "yarn" using : 
`brew upgrade yarn`
This have fixed "react-native-maps" "react-native-branch" and "lottie-react-native" warning, but i still have the first 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how I have fixed my problem

```
brew upgrade yarn
yarn upgrade
yarn cache clean
```

(I know, don't judge me :) )
Then,

```
create-react-native-app .
```

The command "yarn run ios" works well

Orb,

Comment: FYI I still have this warning actually but the application works fine anyway:
`warning react-native-scripts > xdl > auth0-js > xtend > object-keys@0.4.0:`